# Is it safe to pass the pointers to hashed password?

Tags: c++, encryption, aes

I am creating app to encrypt my file with AES. My question: Is it possible to intercept the password and if it is possible, how to protect my password? I am worried about these pointers, because knowing the memory blocks and the way how to decrypt the password would expose my password and my data.

```
string xorfunc(string A, string B)
{
 for(int i=0,j=0;i<A.length();i++,j++)
  {
   if(j==B.length())
   {
      j=0; 
   }
   A[i]=A[i]^B[j];
  }
  return A; 
}

void AESfunction(string *hashed,string *hash)
{
    string password=string(xorfunc(*hashed,*hash)); //restore password
    //Do other AES stuff.
}

int main()
{
string password;
cin>>password;
string *hash=new string(MD5(password));
string *hashed=new string(xorfunc(password,*hash)); //hashed is a pointer to a password
                                             //xor password hash
                                             //keeping password as a not plain string 

password.clear();                             //clearing string to not keeping 
                                              //it in a memory
AESfunction(hashed,hash);
return 0;  
}
```

Comment: That code makes no sense. What is the xor part supposed to achieve (AFAIK string doesn't even overload that operator)? Why are you using an unsalted single iteration MD5?

Comment: “Intercept” from where? If someone outside your program can read the memory space of your program, then they can read the password, yes. But that has nothing to do with you passing around pointers. (You should really clear the password memory as soon as you no longer need it, and I am not aware that `string` even has an `operator^` – in any case, xoring the MD5 on top of the string instead of simply using the MD5 or better a newer hash function is a *terrible* idea.)

Comment: String don't have ^ operator. I used it to claryfy the code. I xor the password to not storing it as a plain text.

Comment: Before you worry about things like this, you need to deal with getting the basics right, such as using salt (and preferably pepper as well), and switching to a hash that hasn't been broken to the degree MD5 has.

Comment: @MKAROL: In fact you used it to obfuscate the code

Comment: @CodesInChaos unsalted single-iteration MD5 have some advantages over traditional password hashing schemes, it allows very fast password validation!